# HTTP Request taking too much time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http, sharepoint, httpresponse

I Created a warm  up Script for Sharepoint 2007 Farm, I am getting all URLs of webapps, sitecollections, sites, webs & subwebs in ArrayLists. After that I am using following code to get responce from each web, but its taking too much time, I was wondering if there is any alternative or better way to do it, and it will take less time/resources.

```
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
                request.Proxy = null;

                if ((userName == null) || (userName == ""))
                {
                    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                }
                else
                {
                    CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
                    myCache.Add(new Uri(URL), authType, new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain));
                    request.Credentials = myCache;
                }

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
                using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {

                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                    dataStream.Close();
                    response.Close();
                }
```

I tried on google but couldn't find much related or I dont know how to make it related to this,

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't worried about overloading the server, split the URL list and fire off 5 or 10 of these processes. There could be a lot of waiting when sending and receiving.